# Azure ADAL with Web API and Native app

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, adal

I currently have a Xamarin Forms app correctly logging in and using Microsoft Azure AD for authentication before accessing a web api that is also configured in Azure.

Now I want to add role based authorization like I used to do using IdentityServer 4.0.
So within my webapi I put this on my controller:

`[Authorize(Roles = "SOMEDOMAIN\\ADGroup")]`

So now I'm trying to follow documentation on the web but people aren't being descriptive enough. I have 1 question but let me first explain my setup.

### For my Native Xamarin App

*Under "Required Permissions*

- I've already added Windows Azure Active Directory
- I've already added my web api

*I edited the Manifest*

- "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",

### For my Web Api

*Under "Required Permissions*

- I've already added Windows Azure Active Directory

*I edited the Manifest*

- "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",

### Question

1) Within each app above, do I need to enable `Read Directory Data` for the `Windows Azure Active Directory` permission?  If not, which one needs it?

Answer (score 0):

In the Application Manifest, the "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup" should add the `groups` claim to the JWT. Then you just need the ObjectId in Azure AD for the Security Group(s) you are trying to target, discussed in detail [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/). The group information is part of the `id_token`, Per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-token-and-claims),

> Provides object IDs that represent the subject's group memberships. These values are unique (see Object ID) and can be safely used for managing access, such as enforcing authorization to access a resource. The groups included in the groups claim are configured on a per-application basis, through the "groupMembershipClaims" property of the application manifest. A value of null will exclude all groups, a value of "SecurityGroup" will include only Active Directory Security Group memberships, and a value of "All" will include both Security Groups and Office 365 Distribution Lists.

Also, read there is a very thorough Wiki on the Github repo for the ADAL library [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki).

Also, here some good resources on that `groups` claim and the last one is sample solution:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/01/22/group-amp-role-claims-use-the-graph-api-to-get-back-isinrole-and-authorize-in-windows-azure-ad-apps/

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/security-and-compliance/azure-active-directory-part-4-group-claims/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/